# WIndows forms app that need to upload files with their size, type and name to a sql DB

Tags: sql-server, winforms, sql-insert

I have some copy pasted and some written by myself code but I am still really confused around the concept of working with an OpeFileDialog and getting the values from it. While debugging the code it feels like it does nothing when I click OK after choosing the file that I want to upload.

this is the code for the form

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace School_Database
{
    public partial class Repository : Form
    {
        public Repository()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Repository_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string query = "SELECT * FROM RepositoryInfoTable";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, DB.connection);


            //here we again open the connection
            DB.openConnection();
            updateDataBinding();

            //updateDataBinding();
        }
        private void Repository_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            DB.closeConnection();
            Application.Exit();
        }


        private void bindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (bindingNavigatorAddNewItem.Text == "Add new") // in order to change the text property to Cancel if it is clicked
                {
                    //on default it clears all the text boxes and makes a new row on the grid 
                    //here we make it imposible to make a empty row by making the user to NOT be able to
                    //interact with somethings on the form and changing what the button does in the "else" statement

                    bindingNavigatorAddNewItem.Text = "Cancel";
                    bindingNavigatorAddNewItem.ToolTipText = "Cancel";

                    //these are the small blue arrows (top left on the form)
                    bindingNavigatorMoveFirstItem.Enabled = false;
                    bindingNavigatorMovePreviousItem.Enabled = false;
                    bindingNavigatorPositionItem.Enabled = false;
                    bindingNavigatorMoveNextItem.Enabled = false;
                    bindingNavigatorMoveLastItem.Enabled = false;

                    //clear the grid
                    dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
                    dataGridView1.Enabled = false;

                    // Create an OpenFileDialog object to let the user select a file
                    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
                    openFileDialog.Filter = "All files|*.*";

                    // Show the OpenFileDialog and get the result
                    DialogResult dialog = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
                    bool isShown = true;

                    // If the user selects a file
                    if (isShown == true)
                    {
                        // Get the file name, type, size, and data
                        FileInfo file = new FileInfo();

                        // Set the file location property
                        string fileLocation = openFileDialog.FileName;
                        string fileLocationDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileLocation);// Example file location
                        file.FileLocation = fileLocationDirectory;

                        // Set the file name property
                        file.FileName = openFileDialog.SafeFileName;

                        // Set the file type property
                        file.FileType = Path.GetExtension(fileLocation);

                        // Set the file size property
                        //long fileSizeInBytes;
                        //FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileLocation);
                        //if (long.TryParse(fileInfo.Length.ToString(), out fileSizeInBytes))
                        //{
                        //    file.FileSize = fileSizeInBytes;
                        //}
                        //else
                        //{
                        //    // Handle the case where the file size is too large to fit in a long data type
                        //    MessageBox.Show("Файлът е твърде голям.");
                        //}


                        // Set the file binary data property
                        file.FileBinaryData = File.ReadAllBytes(fileLocation);

                        // Set the upload date property
                        file.UploadDate = DateTime.Now;

                        // Set the posted by property
                        string postedBy = "Marincho"; // Example username
                        file.PostedBy = postedBy;


                        //string fileName = openFileDialog.FileName;
                        //string fileType = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
                        //long fileSize = new FileInfo(FileSize);
                        //byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);

                        // Get the current date and the logged in user's name
                        DateTime uploadDate = DateTime.Now;

                        // Insert the new file into the RepositoryInfoTable
                        DB.cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                        DB.cmd.CommandText = DB.sql;
                        
                        //insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@file_name", file.FileName);
                        //insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@file_type", file.FileType);
                        //insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@file_size", file.FileSize);
                        //insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@file_binaryData", file.FileBinaryData);
                        //insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@upload_date", uploadDate);
                        //insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@posted_by", postedBy);
                        //insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@file_location", file.FileLocation);

                        DB.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@file_name", file.FileName);
                        DB.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@file_type", file.FileType);
                        DB.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@file_size", file.FileSize);
                        DB.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@file_binaryData", file.FileBinaryData);
                        DB.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@upload_date", uploadDate);
                        DB.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@posted_by", postedBy);
                        DB.cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@file_location", file.FileLocation);

                        DB.connection.Open();
                        string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO RepositoryInfoTable (file_name, file_type, file_size, file_binaryData, upload_date, posted_by, file_location) VALUES (@file_name, @file_type, @file_size, @file_binaryData, @upload_date, @posted_by, @file_location)";

                        SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, DB.connection);
                        int resultCount = insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); //used to execute a SQL INSERT statement and retrieve the number of rows
                                                                           //affected by the query.The ExecuteNonQuery() method is used to execute
                                                                           //a query that does not return any results, such as an
                                                                           //INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement.It returns an integer value
                                                                           //that represents the number of rows affected by the query.

                        // Refresh the DataGridView to show the new file
                        MessageBox.Show(file.FileName + file.FileType + postedBy);
                        DB.dataAdapter.Fill(DB.dataSet, "RepositoryInfoTable");
                        DB.connection.Close();
                        isShown = false;

                    }

                    bindingNavigatorAddNewItem.Text = "Add new";
                    bindingNavigatorAddNewItem.ToolTipText = "Add new";

                    //these are the small blue arrows (top left on the form)
                    bindingNavigatorMoveFirstItem.Enabled = true;
                    bindingNavigatorMovePreviousItem.Enabled = true;
                    bindingNavigatorPositionItem.Enabled = true;
                    bindingNavigatorMoveNextItem.Enabled = true;
                    bindingNavigatorMoveLastItem.Enabled = true;

                    updateDataBinding();
                    return; //The return statement is used to exit a method and return control to the calling code (this one).
                    
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }

        private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void updateDataBinding(SqlCommand command = null, Button btn = null)
        {
            try
            {
                if (command == null)
                {// МОЖЕ ДА ТРЯБВАТ ПРОМЕНИ
                    DB.cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM RepositoryInfoTable ORDER BY upload_date";
                }
                else
                {
                    DB.cmd = command;
                }

                DB.dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(DB.cmd);

                DB.dataSet = new DataSet(); //is an in-memory representation of a relational database that is used to store and manipulate data.
                                            //It can contain one or more DataTable objects, which in turn represent a table of data,
                                            //as well as relationships between tables, constraints, and other metadata.

                // !!! A DB.DataTable is an in-memory representation of a database table. You can use it to store, manipulate,
                // and manage data in your application and only when you press SAVE/UPDATE
                // the changes will be pushed to the original sql DB

                DB.dataAdapter.Fill(DB.dataSet, "StudentList"); // при него е написано TeacherList!!!!
                                                                //In simple terms, Fill method is used to fetch data from a database table and store it in a DataSet or DataTable object for further processing. 
                                                                //Once the data is in the DataSet or DataTable, it can be used for data binding, manipulation, or other operations.
                DB.bindingSrc = new BindingSource(DB.dataSet, "StudentList");

                bindingNavigator1.BindingSource = DB.bindingSrc; // (обекта, който ще работи с данните за да ги визуализира).свойство = (нещото, с което го свързваме а именно нашата връзка с базата данни)

                dataGridView1.Enabled = true; // so we can Interact and change things in the grid
                dataGridView1.DataSource = DB.bindingSrc;
                //Select the full row
                dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells); //Overall, the code ensures that the columns in the DataGridView are automatically resized to fit their contents 
                dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect; //This means that when the user clicks on a cell in the DataGridView, the entire row of the clicked cell will be selected.
                                                                                       //If FullRowSelect is not set, only the clicked cell would be selected instead of the entire row.

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Update Data Bindings Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

this is the DB.cs code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;

namespace School_Database
{
    class DB
    {
        public static SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-0R58GC3\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SchoolDB;Integrated Security=True");

        public static SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("", connection);
        public static DataSet dataSet;
        public static SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter;
        public static BindingSource bindingSrc;

        public static string sql;

        public static void openConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    connection.Open();
                   //if you want to check if your DB connection is okay or not
                   //MessageBox.Show("Connection is: " + connection.State.ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Open Connection has Failed:" + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        public static void closeConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    connection.Close();
                    //MessageBox.Show("Connection is: " + connection.State.ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Close Connection Error:" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the FileInfo.cs code

```
public class FileInfo
    {
        //potentila fixes
        public FileInfo()
        {

        }
        public FileInfo(string fileLocation)
        {
            FileLocation = fileLocation;
        }

        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string FileType { get; set; }
        public long FileSize { get; set; }
        public byte[] FileBinaryData { get; set; }
        public DateTime UploadDate { get; set; }
        public string PostedBy { get; set; }
        public string FileLocation { get; set; }

        //potential fix
        public object Length { get; internal set; }
    }
```

hope that is enough info and I would be more than thankful to anyone suggesting anything and explaining why to do it.(btw there are some commented experimental code lines)

I expect after clicking OK on the dialog box the values to be set and after that a query to insert these values to the corresponding columns in the DB, and to refresh the databinding of the datagridview so I can now see that everything worked fine and if I add the option for file to be downloaded it will work. Basically I need it to upload files and save them into a SQL database as binary data. Should I use StreamWriter and if yes, how to implement it?

Comment: Add some code in your exception handler that logs errors like: Console.WriteLine(ex); This way at least you will see if there's an error. To me your code that handles the file opening looks alright, so it probably bugs out later

Comment: You need to read up about how to manage database connections. The way you have coded this is going to cripple your connection pool. You need to close and dispose connections immediately after using them, not when you close a windows form.

Comment: Also...http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/

Comment: `string query = "SELECT * FROM RepositoryInfoTable"` ... are you sure you want to do that? That will select every column of every row to download to your repository - including every file blob that you've previously uploaded.

Comment: what should I do instead of this "string query = "SELECT * FROM RepositoryInfoTable"", also thanks for informing me for the AddWithValue thing, I was just following a tutorial and didn't realize it's something bad